# Current issue of a Java Style Guide/Coding Standards from an official source

Tags: java, coding-style, code-standards

I'm working on a project which is in the initial stages, and I'm setting up some coding standards and a style guide.  I've been looking for some good sources for coding standards, style guidelines, and best practices in general for Java development.

I've come across the official coding conventions from Oracle, but they appear to be from 1999, so I was wondering if there is anything more current.

FWIW, here is a link to the Oracle doc I found:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you have found is current.  The document has not been updated since 1999.

There are other more recent style guides around, but nothing (public) from Oracle / Sun, and not "official".

Comment: When you use an IDE there is usually an implicit style which will be followed when the code is auto-formatted by the IDE. I find it easier to follow those guidelines (and nominating a preferred IDE) instead of imposing a second set of rules.

Comment: @RudolphEst - that is true.  However, in my experience (Eclipse) an IDE's default auto-formatting covers less than half of what the "official" style guide covers.